# How to fix E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 1044 (packagekitd)

Tags: linux, terminal, multi-boot, apt, ubuntu-22.04

Recently, I have bought a 64GB SD card for dual booting Ubuntu on my computer. It works at first, but when I try to run

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

It gives me this:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 1044 (packagekitd)
```

I have tried the following:

```
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
```

But it still gives me this error. Any help?

Comment: Some other program is probably trying to update. Usually you can just wait it out. You might be able to find it using `ps aux | grep -i apt` or `sudo fuser -vki /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`.

Comment: Wait... what should the output be?

Comment: Lots of advice to be found about how to fix this problem. Here are some links with output that you could try, so let me know if any one fix worked and I'll put it up in an answer. The links are (some methods appear in more than one) : [link1](https://itsfoss.com/could-not-get-lock-error/), [link2](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-could-not-get-lock-error-ubuntu), [link3](https://www.debugpoint.com/could-not-get-lock/).